# Sort array and child arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I have an array like:

```
$array = array(
    4 => array(
         'position' => 0
         'children' => array(
         )
    ),
    2 => array(
         'position' => 0
         'children' => array(
            3 => array(
                'position' => 1
            )
            5 => array(
                'position' => 0
            )
         )
    )
)
```

I need to sort the outer arrays (2 & 4) by key 'position', ascending (0 upwards), and then sort each inner array of those ('children'), by their respective position.

There might be 6 main arrays, with 6 'children' arrays to sort.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your explanation of the problem correctly, following code will work for you:

```
//sort the outer array
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] - $b['position'];
});
//sort childrens
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    usort($item['children'], function($a, $b) {
        return $a['position'] - $b['position'];
    });
}
```

In any case, usort is a native php function that will be very handy for described case. http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: See I did try that. I didn't pass by reference though, could that have been my problem? I have since changed this so I don't need it.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass sub-array by reference in order to change it